how to solve domain name linux server by windows dns server
I have
Windows Server 2012 DNS server with active directory:

192.168.10.10
domain: www.work.local

Debian 12 DNS server:

192.168.10.11
domain: work.it

25 workstations registered in active directory in range 10.16.0.0/24
Fortigate firewall gateway

10.16.0.1
five ports: 10.16.0.0/24
and five ports: 192.168.10.0/24

On the workstations I can't resolve the address work.it of Debian server
on the debian server:
nslookup work.it
Server: 127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: work.it
Address: 192.168.10.11

on the windows server:
/>nslookup work.local
Server: server01.work.local
Address: 192.168.10.10

Name: work.local
Address: 192.168.10.10

on my computer my configuration is:
ip:10.16.0.25
geteway:10.16.0.1
dns1:192.168.10.10
dns2:192.168.10.11

nslookup on my pc:
/>nslookup work.local
Server: server01.work.local
Address: 192.168.10.10

Name: work.local
Address: 192.168.10.10
 />nslookup work.it 
Server: server01.work.local 
Address: 192.168.10.10

*** server01 server01.work.local can't find work.it : Non-existent domain
the question is common i can access www.work.it thanks in advance

I've tried to increase the readability of your question by reformatting.
Let's see if I've understood correctly:
You have two domains:

work.local which is held by an Active Directory environment with 25 workstations and one Domain Controller (server01.work.local, 192.168.10.10)
work.it which is held by a Debian DNS server (192.168.10.11)

Your workstation has the AD DNS as it's primary DNS and the Debian DNS as the secondary.
I'm guessing that you think having both DNS sources will allow you to query both servers simultaneously or sequentially. Unfortunately that's not how Windows DNS works. The primary DNS server will be contacted and used exclusively unless it cannot be reached. The second DNS entry will only be used if the first DNS server is offline.
What you probably need to do is to tell the Windows DNS server how to use the Debian DNS server. There are a couple options:

You can set up a DNS Stub Zone for work.it. This delegates all DNS queries received in AD for work.it to the Debian server
Create a Conditional Forwarder to work.it. This is similar to a Stub zone and forwards all requests for work.it to the Debian server
Use the work.it DNS server as a forwarder. This tells the Windows server to forward all requests it can't handle to the Debian server. This may not be a good idea depending on your setup.

You'll need to also create the reverse, telling the Debian DNS server how to query the work.local domain.
